# Invoke POST method using Breeze not working

Tags: breeze, hottowel

I am working on single page application using HotTowel. I have referred below link for invoking POST method using breeze.

http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezeajaxpostjs

Below is my code.

On Server side:

```
  public struct Customer {
            public string CompanyName{ get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
        } 

    [HttpPost]
    public IQueryable<Customer> SimilarCustomersPOST(Customer customer)
    {
        return repository.CustomersLikeThis(customer);
    }
```

Invoking POST method using breeze.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('SimilarCustomersPOST')
       .withParameters({
           $method: 'POST',
           $encoding: 'JSON',
           $data: { CompanyName: 'Hilo' , Phone: '808-234-5678' }
       });
```

I am getting below error:
Error: The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

When I am writing a server code like below:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
 [HttpPost]
        public IQueryable<Customer> SimilarCustomersPOST(Customer customer)
        {
            return repository.CustomersLikeThis(customer);
        }
```

It is invoking but accepted parameters getting null values.

Please let me know what is the reason I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happens when you mix `[HttpPost]` with `[AcceptVerbs("GET")]`, but that might be the problem.

Note that in a GET method you need to use the `[FromUri]` attribute in front of parameters that are not simple value types, but you don't need that in a POST method.  [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) explains WebAPI parameter binding nicely.